# MS Access Query to output all values and treat unavailable values as zero

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've created a query MS Access 2010 that is intended to take all fuel types (all values) for each date.  I have the query relationship below: [image: Figure1]) and have the following 6 values for fuel type: Diesel #2, MSFO, ULSD, Biodiesel, Used Oil, Heat Recovery.

I'm trying to output the fuel delivery for each fuel type for each date regardless if there's any fuel delivered that date 
[image: (Figure2] 
and 
[image: Figure3)].  What I'm getting as my output is below
[image: Figure4].

I have tried to change the relationships such that all values on tbl_FuelType would output.  This gave me the output on the figure above.  I've tried entering a criteria to look for the specific fuel type (e.g. "ULSD") but if there's no data for that day, it will output with Null values, which I don't want. See criteria below
[image: Figure5]
I've tried some program flow functions such as IIF and Switch but still getting null values.  Is there an easy way to do this without having to go into the table and filling out values as zero's for all the different fuel types on the tbl_FuelDelivery?  The SQL view is as follows:

```html
SELECT tbl_FuelDelivery.DateLog, Sum(Nz([tbl_FuelDelivery].[F_FO_gal_Gross],0)) AS Fuel_Delivery_Gross, Sum(Nz([tbl_FuelDelivery].[F_FO_gal_Net],0)) AS Fuel_Delivery_Net, tbl_FuelType.FuelType
FROM tbl_FuelType LEFT JOIN tbl_FuelDelivery ON tbl_FuelType.ID = tbl_FuelDelivery.FuelType
GROUP BY tbl_FuelDelivery.DateLog, tbl_FuelType.FuelType
ORDER BY tbl_FuelDelivery.DateLog;
​
```

Comment: Please switch to the SQL View and show us the SQL Query

Comment: Added SQL view to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to add to your query is a table with all dates. You can have a separate table where all dates are entered, such a calendar table or have it derived from your `tbl_FuelDelivery` like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_FuelDelivery.DateLog 
FROM tbl_FuelDelivery;
```

Now, you need to CROSS JOIN this table with tbl_FuelType. Access does not natively support cross joins, so you'll have to use a workaround: just add the cross join as a comma separated table to your FROM clause:

```
SELECT a.DateLog, tbl_FuelType.FuelType, tbl_FuelType.ID
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tbl_FuelDelivery.DateLog FROM tbl_FuelDelivery) a, 
tbl_FuelType;
```

The query above will give you the all fuel types for all dates. You can save it as a new query (let's call it allDatesFuels). Now, all you need to do is to join it with your query:

```
SELECT 
allDatesFuels.DateLog, 
Sum(Nz([tbl_FuelDelivery].[F_FO_gal_Gross],0)) AS Fuel_Delivery_Gross, 
Sum(Nz([tbl_FuelDelivery].[F_FO_gal_Net],0)) AS Fuel_Delivery_Net, 
allDatesFuels.FuelType
FROM allDatesFuels LEFT JOIN tbl_FuelDelivery ON allDatesFuels.ID = tbl_FuelDelivery.FuelType And allDatesFuels.DateLog = tbl_FuelDelivery.DateLog
GROUP BY allDatesFuels.DateLog, allDatesFuels.FuelType
ORDER BY allDatesFuels.DateLog;
​
```

Comment: Cha, getting an error when I try to do the work around, see answer 2.

Comment: Sorry, made a typo. You should have used the tbl_FuelType in the allDatesFuels query. I have corrected the answer. BTW, do not make answers if you want to comment, just use the comments section here

Comment: No worries, I tried the first query you mentioned above, but I'm getting a prompt to "Enter Parameter Value" for DateLog.  Then when I press Ok or even input a value, I get this error: "This expression is typed incorrectly, or it is too complex to be evaluated.  For example, a numeric expression may contain too many complicated elements.  Try simplifying the expression by assigning parts of the expression to variables."

Comment: awesome, It's working now.  I've never used that SELECT DISTINCT syntax.  Thanks so much!